# How to open link in new tab after onClick function finishes running?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, anchor, href

I have a link that, when clicked, will open in a new tab. However, determining that link actually requires a heavy computation. The intended sequence of effect I need are:

1. User clicks on link
2. Several seconds pass to determine the link that is needed.
3. A new tab will open with the calculated link.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Once you get the calculated link, use window.open(url) to open in a new tab

Comment: @SabirAmeen and it will be blocked in browsers

Comment: @karthick Even if it's user initiated?

Comment: @SabirAmeen what do you mean by user initiated ? window.open is normally blocked in chrome if it's coming from a script

Comment: @karthick if it was executed due to a click event.

Comment: @SabirAmeen: Yes agreed. But in this case if it was calculated then isnt that request coming from a script. But that's something the OP needs to confirm

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.open(calculateURL, '_blank');` but remember that different browsers implement the behavior of `window.open()` differently. It actually depends on the user's browser's settings. For example, Chrome would block the popup when you run the above code.

Answer (score 0):

As SabirAmeen said, if you know the time it'll take to determine the link then just open the new tab in setTimeout passing the determined time or else if you know the url have specific character then just use the searchIndex or url hash to open a new tab.